# Leave, pour or drop

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I would like others to tell me which verb is correct in these sentences. Is there another verb which fits best?

> 1. I was **leaving** sand from my hand slowly.
> 2. I was **dropping** sand from my hand slowly.
> 3. I was **pouring** sand from my hand slowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitive "pour" usually implies not just intention, but also attention: "I was pouring sand from my hand" suggests that I was carefully pouring it into some vessel, or for some particular purpose. (Intransitive "pour" doesn't have this implication: "the sand poured out of my hand" doesn't say anything about my intention).

Transitive "drop" can be intentional, but it is more often unintentional. "I dropped the sand" is probably unintentional, or at least not careful. "I was dropping sand from my hand slowly is probably intentional, but suggests less care about the process than "pouring".

"Leaving" doesn't work this way at all. You leave a place (or a person), you don't leave something from somewhere: that is not among the maeanings of the word.

Answer (score 2):

Both pouring and dropping make sense here, but in this context I would say that “Pouring” works better as sand (especially with the “Slowly” you included) would  behave very much like a liquid for this action.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You were letting sand  pour slowly out of your hand.

You were letting sand slowly out of your hand.

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> Is there another verb which fits best?

I would one of the following different descriptions:

> You let sand slowly **flow** from your hand.
>   You let sand **trickle** from your hand.

---

The definition of meaning [*trickle*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trickle) includes the concept of slowness, so it doesn't need to be part of the description.

Also, the Wikipedia entry for [*hourglass*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hourglass) uses the word *trickle*. It says:

> An hourglass (or sandglass, sand timer, or sand clock) is a device used to measure the passage of time. It comprises two glass bulbs connected vertically by a narrow neck that allows a regulated trickle of material (historically sand) from the upper bulb to the lower one.